# Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith' but I do not use it

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I have a React app and when I start it in IE11(all the others work) it says :

Object doesn't support property or method endsWith, but I never use this function... Here is the problem:

```
./node_modules/@nivo/core/cjs/nivo-core.js
G:/Work/ReactApp/react/node_modules/@nivo/core/cjs/nivo-core.js:1632
1629 | 
1630 | var curvePropType = PropTypes.oneOf(curvePropKeys);
1631 | 
1632 | var closedCurvePropKeys = curvePropKeys.filter(function (c) {
1633 |     return c.endsWith('Closed');
1634 | });
1635 |
```

Comment: Some of your modules is using it. You should add a polyfill then.

Comment: this should be a comment though, unless u add a sample on how to import the polyfill or where to get it

Comment: I did some research and I find out how. I included     <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js? 
                                                   
            features=default,String.prototype.endsWith()"></script> in my index.html and now it works :) . Thank you!